# How to add correctly a toggle switch in Odoo website

Tags: html, css, web, bootstrap-4, odoo

I want to add a toggle switch in the header of my Odoo template.
I found this code on Bootstrap

```
<div class="custom-control custom-switch">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitch1">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitch1">Toggle this switch element</label>
</div>
```

it works perfectly on laptop but when I try it on tablet, the header disappear.

On Laptop :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUXSs.png)

On Tablet :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLRHv.jpg)

I'm not using any CSS, what the reason that makes the header disappear on tablet?

Using Google Chrome on Tablet Samsung Galaxy TAB lite, android version 4.4.4

I tried another code of toggle switch, same problem.

I tried on tablet iPad, same problem.

Here is the full code:

```
<div id="top_menu_collapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse ml-lg-3">
                    <t t-call="website.navbar_nav">
                        <t t-set="_nav_class" t-valuef="flex-grow-1"/>
                        <!-- Menu -->
                        <t t-foreach="website.menu_id.child_id" t-as="submenu">
                            <t t-call="website.submenu">
                                <t t-set="item_class" t-valuef="nav-item"/>
                                <t t-set="link_class" t-valuef="nav-link"/></t>
                        </t>
                        <!--Toggle Swith-->
                        <span style="margin-top: -15px; margin-left: 10px" >
                            <center>
                                <b>Prix</b>
                            </center>
                            <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
                                <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitch1"/>
                                <label id="custom-switch-on-off" class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitch1"></label>
                            </div>
                        </span>
                        <!-- Sign In -->
                        <t t-call="portal.placeholder_user_sign_in">
                            <t t-set="_item_class" t-valuef="nav-item ml-lg-auto"/>
                            <t t-set="_link_class" t-valuef="nav-link"/></t>
                        <!-- User Dropdown -->
                        <t t-call="portal.user_dropdown">
                            <t t-set="_user_name" t-value="True"/>
                            <t t-set="_user_name_class" t-valuef="font-weight-bold"/>
                            <t t-set="_item_class" t-valuef="nav-item dropdown ml-lg-auto"/>
                            <t t-set="_link_class" t-valuef="nav-link"/></t>
                    </t>
                    
                    <!-- Language Selector -->
                    <t t-call="website.placeholder_header_language_selector">
                        <t t-set="_div_classes" t-valuef="my-auto ml-lg-2 align-self-lg-center"/></t>
                    <!-- Call To Action -->
                    <t t-call="website.placeholder_header_call_to_action">
                        <t t-set="_div_classes" t-valuef="d-none d-lg-block ml-3"/></t>
                </div>
```

Comment: Can you include your header HTML code to the question? I'm not sure without seeing your code but probably the reason is that you placed the toggle switch in collapsable part of the header.

Comment: I just added the rest of the code, can you please check it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to put toggle switch outside of `navbar_nav`. See below:

```
<div id="top_menu_collapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse ml-lg-3">
    <t t-call="website.navbar_nav">
        <t t-set="_nav_class" t-valuef="flex-grow-1"/>
        <!-- Menu -->
        <t t-foreach="website.menu_id.child_id" t-as="submenu">
            <t t-call="website.submenu">
                <t t-set="item_class" t-valuef="nav-item"/>
                <t t-set="link_class" t-valuef="nav-link"/>
            </t>
        </t>
        <!-- Sign In -->
        <t t-call="portal.placeholder_user_sign_in">
            <t t-set="_item_class" t-valuef="nav-item ml-lg-auto"/>
            <t t-set="_link_class" t-valuef="nav-link"/>
        </t>
        <!-- User Dropdown -->
        <t t-call="portal.user_dropdown">
            <t t-set="_user_name" t-value="True"/>
            <t t-set="_user_name_class" t-valuef="font-weight-bold"/>
            <t t-set="_item_class" t-valuef="nav-item dropdown ml-lg-auto"/>
            <t t-set="_link_class" t-valuef="nav-link"/>
        </t>
    </t>
    <!--Toggle Swith-->
    <span style="margin-top: -15px; margin-left: 10px">
        <center>
            <b>Prix</b>
        </center>
        <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitch1"/>
            <label id="custom-switch-on-off" class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitch1"></label>
        </div>
    </span>
    <!-- Language Selector -->
    <t t-call="website.placeholder_header_language_selector">
        <t t-set="_div_classes" t-valuef="my-auto ml-lg-2 align-self-lg-center"/>
    </t>
    <!-- Call To Action -->
    <t t-call="website.placeholder_header_call_to_action">
        <t t-set="_div_classes" t-valuef="d-none d-lg-block ml-3"/>
    </t>
</div>
```

Comment: It is a solution, but what I have been asked for is that the toggle has be in that place! I couldn't find a solution to this track.